# How to resize a loaded image?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I'm currently hand-painting my character's texture using Blender's `Texture Paint` mode. However, halfway through painting, I realized that the image I created for texture painting is in a smaller resolution than what I want. The image is currently at 1024x1024. Is it possible to resize/scale it to 2048x2048 inside Blender?

[image: Texture paint dimensions]

Comment: imho not inside blender, but you can resize it outside easily, and then simply push the "reload" button in blender...

Comment: Another way would be baking from lower res image to higher res.

Answer (score 3):

Type this in the blender console:

bpy.data.images["**ImageName**"].scale(x, y)

x, y = desired size of the image

In your case:

bpy.data.images["texture_paint_..."].scale(2048, 2048)

Old topic, but I found this code in the 2.78's API.  So we officially have a way to resize image inside blender.

Comment: This could be the basis for a small addon I think, a few options to get the image name and the current x and y scale and then allow resizing to original or copy. I think I might tackle it. Thank you for the tip here, TeaCrab.

Comment: My friend Patrick helped me fix up a small addon for this. It is really simple and clean now and in the Image Editor in the UI panel. https://github.com/artistCDMJ/image_editor_scale/archive/master.zip

Comment: Hey Craig, you are welcome!  : ). I’ll check it out later.  At work right now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, actually. Using Texture Paint even.

1. Save the current image to disk. I made mine *"first.png"*
2. Create a new image in UV Image Editor at 2048x2048, save to disk as *"second.png"*
3. Import your *"first.png"* into the 3d view with Import Images as Planes addon(ships with blender, just turn it on).
4. In material texture stack, add *"second.png"* to material for the  *"first.png"* plane.
5. In 3d viewport > Toolshelf in the Slots tab, make the *"second.png"* as the active paint slot.
6. Choose the Clone brush tool ,and choose *"first.png"* as the Source Clone Slot and tick the option to Clone form paint slot.
7. Paint with a 1.000 strength brush as large as you want, and you will transfer the image from the 1k *"first.png"* to the 2k *"second.png"*.
8. Since you saved both texture images to disk already, merely press *Save All Images* button in the Slots tab to write the change to the *"second.png"*.
9. Reload the *"second.png"* as the new texture to your 3d model.